# Python convert long to date

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a long to a date:

```
class timeStamp(object):
     def getDateTime(self,longDate):                                                                                                                                 
         myNumber = float(longDate)
         return str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.ctime(myNumber)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

But I have a weird error:

```
 File "./index.py", line 104, in getDateTime
    return str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.ctime(myNumber)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
TypeError: a float is required
```

Why is it complaining when I explicitly cast it to float? The long is a Unix timestamp stored as a long in mysql.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is simply
`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(myNumber).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` as `time.ctime()` returns a string:

```
>>> time.ctime()
'Sat May 19 13:46:09 2012'
```

Comment: long time should be in seconds, otherwise (in ms) it throws an error

Answer (score 14):

`time.ctime()` gives you the string representation of the time.

it should work with:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(myNumber).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```